# Does this relationship have a name?

Tags: probability, terminology

Suppose we have two finite discrete probability distributions, say $A$ and $B$. For some event $e$ in both $A$ and $B$, $f_A(e) = \frac{P_A(e)}{P_A(e) + P_B(e)}$ and $f_B(e) = \frac{P_B(e)}{P_A(e) + P_B(e)}$. Does this have a name?

Comment: This looks like a conditional probability. For example, $f_{A}(e)$ looks something like the conditional probability that event $e$ came from $A$ given that we know it came from either $A$ or $B$.

Comment: This is [Bayes formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) under a $(1/2,1/2)$ prior probability on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Macro: assuming the model assures us that $e$ cannot occur in both $A$ and $B$ at the same time.

Comment: $e$ absolutely can occur in both $A$ and $B$ at the same time, which is why I said "For some event $e$ in both $A$ and $B$"

Comment: can you clarify your notation a bit?  What do you mean by f_A(e)?  What about P_A(e) ?